# How to programmatically show a window/view controller in Swift 4 for macOS application

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I'm trying to programmatically show a window in my macOS application. The reason I want to do it programmatically is because the user clicks a Login button and the resulting function depends on the success of the login. If it was successful, the window is shown; otherwise, it is not.

Here is a screenshot of my Xcode window:

[image: xcode window screenshot]

Here's what I'm trying in the code (`Alert` is a class I created to make showing `NSAlert` dialogs easier):

```
@IBAction func btnLogin_Click(_ sender: Any) {
    let email = txtEmail.stringValue
    if(email.isEmpty) {
        Alert.show(parent: view.window!, message: "Email is required.")
        return
    }

    let password = txtPassword.stringValue
    if(password.isEmpty) {
        Alert.show(parent: view.window!, message: "Password is required.")
        return
    }

    // this does not work, even though I gave the window and view controllers
    // both identifiers in the storyboard
    self.storyboard?.instantiateController(withIdentifier: NSStoryboard.SceneIdentifier("wcStores"))
}
```

Apple's documentation for [`NSStoryboard.SceneIdentifier`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsstoryboard.sceneidentifier) is pretty much nonexistent, and other methods I've seen seem to pertain to earlier versions of Swift.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have only set an identifier.   And you are not instantiating NSWindowController.

Comment: @ElTomato thanks for your comment, new to Swift and Mac development so bear with me. I added my own answer since I finally figured out how to do what I really wanted to do in the first place.

Comment: If you are happy with your solution, that'll be find with me as well.  I'm not going to answer it, but I would try to find out why NSWindowController is connected to the main view controller in the first place if I were you.

Answer (score 5):

Alright, so this is not what I originally was trying to do, but this way is much better, and what I was really looking for.

```
let vcStores = self.storyboard?.instantiateController(withIdentifier: NSStoryboard.SceneIdentifier("vcStores"))
        as! NSViewController
self.view.window?.contentViewController = vcStores
```

This will just replace the window's contents with the contents in the view `vcStores` as defined in Interface Builder.

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WqZhXfWe_oY) also helped, albeit for iOS and Swift 3. I was trying to create a new `NSWindow` at first because I'm so used to doing desktop development in Java Swing or C# Windows Forms. But I love how easy it is to just switch out the window contents like this.

Answer (score 0):

> Use these two function to go to the target
> NSViewcontroller/UIViewcontroller: (you must assign a unique
> storyboard id to the target view controller)

[image]

Mac APP:

```
 public func gotToNextVc(_ viewControllerIdentifier: String) {
        let nextVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateController(withIdentifier: NSStoryboard.SceneIdentifier(viewControllerIdentifier))
                    as! NSViewController
                self.view.window?.contentViewController = nextVC
        }
```

IOS APP:

```
public func gotToNextVc(_ viewControllerIdentifier: String){
    let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: ViewControllers.STORYBOARD, bundle: nil)
    let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: viewControllerIdentifier)
    view.endEditing(true)
    nextViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    nextViewController.modalTransitionStyle = .coverVertical
    self.present(nextViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
```